# Question About Recession Cone for an Indicator Function

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider an indicator function $I$ defined as
$$
I\left( {x,y} \right): =  \begin{cases}
 0,&\left( {x,y} \right) \in  [0,+\infty) \times   [0,+\infty)\\
   + \infty, & \text{otherwise} \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
I want to find the "recession cone of its epigraph"; namely, I want to find $rc (epi (I) )$.

Here is my thinking: $epi(I)$ is the set $\{( (x,y), \xi) \in \mathbb{R}^{2+1}: x\geq 0, y \geq 0\}$ which gives me the same $rc(epic(I))$. That is,
$$
rc(epi (I) ) = \{(x,y) \times \mathbb{R}_+ : x \geq 0, y \geq 0\}
$$
 Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the epigraph of $I$ is a cone. Hence, it equals its recession cone.